# why is my endpoint not cleaning a specific part of my code

Tags: python, list, function

I have written this code however I need the getEndPoint function to work with the clean function so that the function will repeatedly prompt the user for the 'end point' (last included row and column) on which the count and the clean operations will occur.
For instance if the user enters a row of 3 and a column of 3 then the two operations will occur from row 0 to row 3 and from column 0 to column 3 (i.e. the whole list).
If the user enters a row of 0 and a column of 0 then count and cleaning will only occur on the first element.

I know that I have passed the parameters from the getEndPoint function to include them in the clean function but I do not know how to use them in a way that my code will use the endpoint and only clean what I want it to.

```
SIZE = 4
EMPTY = " "
PERSON = "P"
PET = "T"
POOP = "O"
ERROR = "!"
CLEANED = "."
MAX_RANDOM = 10

def clean(world,endRow,endColumn):
        print("Scooping the poop")
        for r in range(SIZE):
            for c in range(SIZE):
                if world[r][c] == POOP:
                    world[r][c] = CLEANED
            
                    
# @args(reference to a alist of characters,integer,integer)
# Function will count the number of occurences of the character specified by the user up the specified
# end point (row/column specified by the user).
# @return(character,integer)
def count(world,endRow,endColumn):
    print("Counting number of occurances of a character")
    number = 0
    element = input("Enter character: ")
    for r in range(SIZE):
        for c in range(SIZE):
            if world[r][c] == element:
                number += 1 
    return(element,number)

# Randomly generates an 'occupant' for a location in the world
# @args(none)
# Randomly generates and returns a character according to the specified probabilities.
#  *50% probability empty space
#  *20% probability of a person
#  *10% probability of a pet
#  *20% probability of fecal matter
# @return(character)
def createElement():
    tempNum = random.randrange(MAX_RANDOM)+1

    # 50% chance empty
    if ((tempNum >= 1) and (tempNum <= 5)):
        tempElement = EMPTY 

    # 20% of a person
    elif ((tempNum >= 6) and (tempNum <= 7)):
        tempElement = PERSON

    # 10% chance of pet
    elif (tempNum == 8):
        tempElement = PET

    # 20% chance of poop in that location (lots in this world)
    elif ((tempNum >= 9) and (tempNum <= 10)):
        tempElement = POOP

    # In case there's a bug in the random number genrator
    else:
        tempElement = ERROR

    return(tempElement)

# Creates the SIZExSIZE world. Randomly populates it with the 
# return values from function createElement
# @args(none)
# Randomly populates the 2D list which is returned to the caller.
# @return(reference to a list of characters)
def createWorld():
    world = [] #  Create a variable that refers to a 1D list. 
    r = 0

    #  Outer 'r' loop traverses the rows. 
    # Each iteration of the outer loop creates a new 1D list.
    while (r < SIZE):
        tempRow = []  
        world.append(tempRow)  # Create new empty row
        c = 0
        # The inner 'c' loop traverses the columns of the newly 
        # created 1D list creating and initializing each element
        # to the value returned by createElement()
        while (c < SIZE):
            element = createElement()
            tempRow.append(element)
            c = c + 1
        r = r + 1    
    return(world)

# Shows the elements of the world. All the elements in a row will
# appear on the same line.
# @args(reference to a list of characters)
# Displays the 2D list with each row on a separate line.
# @return(nothing)
def display(world):
    print("OUR WORLD")
    print("========")
    r = 0
    while (r < SIZE): # Each iteration accesses a single row 
        c = 0
        while (c < SIZE):  # Each iteration accesses an element in a row
            print(world[r][c], end="")
            c = c + 1
        print()  # Done displaying row, move output to the next line
        r = r + 1 

# @args(none)
# @return(integer,integer)
def getEndPoint():
    endRow = int(input("Enter the row (0-3): "))
    while not 0 <= endRow <= 3:
        print("Invalid input. Value must be in range 0-3")
        endRow = int(input("Enter the row: "))
    endColumn = int(input("Enter the column (0-3): "))
    while not 0 <= endColumn <= 3:
        print("Invalid input. Value must be in range 0-3")
        endColumn = int(input("Enter the column: "))
    return(endRow,endColumn)

# Starting execution point for the program.
def start():
    world = createWorld()
    display(world)
    endRow, endColumn = getEndPoint()
    element, number = count(world, endRow, endColumn)
    print("# occurances of %s=%d" % (element, number))
    clean(world, endRow, endColumn)    
    display(world)
start()
```

Comment: The solution should be clear.  Your `clean` function asks for an ending row and column, but you don't use those values.  Instead, you end the ranges at `SIZE`.  Don't you think, if you want the loop to stop at `endRow`, then it should be in the range?  `for r in range(endRow+1):`.

Comment: Yes that does work I had not added one into it when I tried it before and it was not working properly because of that thank you